# Widthstep issue in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image-processing, uiimage, pixel

While doing image processing with UI images in Objective-C, i am having an unusual image-skewed problem for some images. The images are getting distorted badly. This problem occurs in Open-CV when i take width instead of width-step. 
I know that this problem is created for images whose width is not a multiple of 4 (improper row allignment), my question is how do i fix the issue in Objective-C ??

My sample code:-

```
   unsigned char *output_image1 = (unsigned char *)malloc(height2*width2*4);
   int i,j;

   for(i=0;i<height2;i++){
     for(j=0;j<4*width2;j=j+4){
         output_image[i*4*width2+4*(j/4)]   = 46;
         output_image[i*4*width2+4*(j/4)+1] = 100;
        output_image[i*4*width2+4*(j/4)+2] = 150;
         output_image[i*4*width2+4*(j/4)+3] = 255;
   }
  }
```

Comment: this have nothing to do with ObjC and what are you trying to do? can't you append to image to enforce the alignment?

Comment: I am trying to access pixels individually and modify them. Actually, alignment is not the real problem, the image is getting garbled, to be precise.

Comment: in what way you want to modify the image?

Comment: Add a filter/rotate image etc. I am just resampling the image while loading it... this is where I face the problem.

Comment: there is output_image, but i did not see where is the input come from in your code

Comment: I am now trying with CGImageGetBytesPerRow (imageRef) instead of 4*width2, mainly for reconstruction of the bitmap from raw-data but now a crashing issue occurs.

Comment: The numbers i gave are just example RGB values where in my actual code it is input_image[i*4*width2 + 4*(j/4)] for red, input_image[i*4*width2 + 4*(j/4) + 1] for green... etc

Comment: The problem is fixed.. i used :int step = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);